# Typescript how to get enum key as enum by value and retrieve value from Map?

Tags: typescript, angular11

I have a simple code in angular code to retrieve file image icon based on extension:

```
export enum FileExtension {
    PDF = 'pdf',
    JPEG = 'jpeg'
}

export const FileExtensionIconMap = new Map<FileExtension, string>([
    [FileExtension.PDF, 'fas fa-file-pdf'],
    [FileExtension.JPG, 'fas fa-file-image']
}
```

method to retrieve iconName based on file extension:

```
let iconName = '';
switch (fileExtension) {
    case FileExtension.PDF:
        iconName = FileExtensionIconMap.get(FileExtension.PDF);
        break;
    case FileExtension.PNG:
        iconName = FileExtensionIconMap.get(FileExtension.PNG);
        break;
    
}
return iconName;
```

I have long list of files. Instead of using switch case is there a wayto get value from the Map?

ie. from the 'fileExtension' which will have for eg: 'pdf' is there a way to retrieve the enum key ie. FileExtension.PDF so that i can make this logic in one single line to get value from the map?

tried the following and getting undefined as the result

```
let x = <FileExtension>FileExtension['pdf'];
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could drop the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/w14ZlW) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Comment: Why not just `FileExtensionIconMap.get(fileExtension)` where `fileExtension` is of type `FileExtension` enum? Should work without any switch.

Comment: @tymzap i get undefined when get FileExtension['pdf'] for eg;

Comment: You can't use enums like this. `pdf` is just an object value in enum internal structure, so this value is by no means unique. It's not meant to perform search by it. If you need this `pdf` key you should probably restructure your enum for it to be your key, not value.